# Jquery, update field and enable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, groovy

please help me on this issues
I got 2 text fields, 2 select boxes and button

```
<input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName/>
<select id='selectBox1'>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='lastName' id='lastName/>
<select id='selectBox2'>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>
```

the requirements are: (none field required)

- if firstName has value, if selectBox1 has no value, button must be disable
- if firstName has value, if selectBox1 has value, enable button
- Same rules as lastName field and selectBox2.

Please help, thanks.
This code I tried so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#firstName').change(function(){
       if($('#firstName').val() != '' && $('#selectBox1).val() == ''{
              $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
       }else {
              $('#button').removeAttr('disabled')
       }
   });

   $('#lastName').change(function(){
       if($('#lastName').val() != '' && $('#selectBox2).val() == ''{
              $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
       }else {
              $('#button').removeAttr('disabled')
       }
   });

   $('#selectBox1').change(function(){
       if($('#firstName').val() == '' && $('#selectBox1).val() == ''{
              $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
       }else {
              $('#button').removeAttr('disabled')
       }
   });

   $('#selectBox2').change(function(){
       if($('#lastName').val() == '' && $('#selectBox2).val() == ''{
              $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
       }else {
              $('#button').removeAttr('disabled')
       }
   });
});
```

However, this way is suck. It can't catch all conditions and too long, I am looking for a new way suck as count firstName and selectBox1, if it is even then enable button else disable, but that's my idea, I don't know how to code it.

Comment: please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried any code to do this yet?

Comment: Sure, let me show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged jQuery in your question, but you may find the [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) library is more helpful here to bind the values of elements to model variables and represent the logic for enabling/disabling the button.

To see this mocked up, have a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tW2h6/).

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName' data-bind='value: firstName'/>
<select id='selectBox1' data-bind='value: select1'>
   <option></option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='lastName' id='lastName' data-bind='value: lastName'/>
<select id='selectBox2' data-bind='value: select2'>
   <option></option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' id='submit' data-bind='enable: okToSubmit'>Submit</button>
<br/>
OK to submit: <span data-bind='text: okToSubmit'></span>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function Model () {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable();
    self.lastName = ko.observable();
    self.select1 = ko.observable();
    self.select2 = ko.observable();

    self.okToSubmit = ko.computed(function() {
        return (
                (self.firstName() && self.select1())
                || (!self.firstName() && !self.select1())
            ) && (
                (self.lastName() && self.select2())
                || (!self.lastName() && !self.select2())
            );
    })
};

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it solved my problem, but hard to understand, anyway thanks for help. I tried to analyse ur code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some improvements, this is a fast response.
But you have to add an option value into select tag.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>
<select id="selectBox1">
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"/>
<select id="selectBox2">
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#firstName,#selectBox1,#lastName,#selectBox2').change(function(){
            checkName();
        })
    });

    $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");

    function checkName() {
        if (($('#firstName').val()!='' && $('#selectBox1').val()!='0')||($('#lastName').val()!='' && $('#selectBox2').val()!='0')) {
            $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        }else{
            alert("DIS");
            $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```